# Pass class name to method on Android

Tags: android

On Android Jelly Bean SDK I have a library project where I need to pass a package dependent class name to a constructor

```
       Tab tab4 = actionBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.acc)
           .setTabListener(new TabListener<Account>(
                this, "Accounts", Account.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab4);
```

The Account class is defined in the main project, and as there are a few 'main' projects using the same library. How do I pass the package name + class name to the setTabListener method.

With intents I have done this

```
   intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getSherlockActivity().getPackageName(),
                         getSherlockActivity().getPackageName() + ".Account"))
```

The following obviously doesn't work but how do I replace, I need the main project
class as a type to pass to the constructor

```
     Tab tab4 = actionBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.acc)
           .setTabListener(new TabListener<getPackageName + ".Account">(
                this, "Accounts", getPackageName + ".Account"));
    actionBar.addTab(tab4);
```

Thanks

Comment: What you've done should work, since from Class<?> object you can call getPackage() to get the package name (of the class, not the application). If you need the application's package name, just pass it in as a string. I'm not entirely sure what this is trying to accomplish, so I can't be more use without more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
getClass().getSimpleName()
```

to get a class name.

or

`getPackageName()` of the Context class